# reduce interface size without increasing the resolution

Tags: unity, gnome, resolution

the display of my laptop can't go beyond 1280x800, so the interface (like title, navigation or menu bars) appears bulky if compared to higher resolutions (or even Win7 at the same resolution), stealing space from the contents.

Is it possible to have a "slimmer" interface without increasing the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, if you go to `System settings` (the icon is like a cog and spanner in the launcher) and select `Appearance` you'll see a section for `Launcher icon size`. The slider there lets you decrease the launcher size within limits. As far as application chromes (title bars etc) go I think Unity's defaults give as much space as possible.